# The operand can't be null, so the condition is always true

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I am registering details in FireBase_Auth but since the type it take is not null and the value I want to take is nullable so that my if condition gets true . (if anyone has different solution to it kindly reply).

```
 final newUser = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                        email: email, password: password);
                    if(newUser != null){
                      Navigator.pushNamed(context, ChatScreen.id);
                    }
```

The variable are declared as

```
 final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  String? email;
  String? password  ;
```

**passing error**

The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.

The operand can't be null, so the condition is always true

Comment: for the first one use email as email! and password as password!.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you want. `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` takes two strings, both of which need to be not null. If you have only nullable variables, you have to check whether they are non-null first before you pass them.

As for the return value, you don't need to check whether it's null, because it cannot be null. The return value of this method is `Future<UserCredential>` not `Future<UserCredential?>`. You can remove that line. If you want to account for errors, use try/catch blocks.

```
if(email != null && password != null) {
    try { 
        final newUser = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, ChatScreen.id);
    } catch(e) {
        // handle error here
    }
}
```

Comment: In my opinion this is not  a true answer because you are  not taking into account the server side return value .   newUser can be returned as a null from the server side  because it is possible !  while it may not be as frequent but still it is possible . The above solution does not account for what happens  when newUser retuned  is null in the try block  it only accounts for if a error  is returned  in catch .  It's not a enterprise level solution .

Comment: @user3548161 "The above solution does not account for what happens when newUser retuned is null" indeed, because it cannot be null. The return value is non-nullable, that is the whole point in the OPs compiler warning message. Why do you think it could return null?

Comment: sir , you are failing to take into account that on the Firebase side they have there own developers and from time to time interns work on production ready platforms ,The scenario does not take into account the event that if the developers on firebase side change the source code whether purposely or in error to return a null .. There are many reasons and cases during testing debugging this could be done by new interns as its commonly seen across the industry all the time ... So your solution hasn't accounted for Human error on the Vendor side and has not offered prevention

Comment: I don't think you understand what null-safety means in Dart. They cannot do what you described, *it would not compile*. The return value of this method is `Future<UserCredential>` **not** `Future<UserCredential?>`. You can check it in their [Source on GitHub](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/c88b51105ed1ee70852ed195481560a889aadb2b/packages/firebase_auth/firebase_auth/lib/src/firebase_auth.dart#L231)